# ElasticSearch query for getting exact results from Documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index (name: "index1") pointing to multiple documents in ElasticSearch.

The format(json) of a document is -

```
{
  "_index": "index1",
  "_type": "someType",
  "_id": "randomIDBlahBlah",
  "_source": {
    "version": "2018",
    "fields": [
      {
        "field": "A.B",
        "lineNumber": 1
      },
      {
        "field": "C.D",
        "lineNumber": 2
      },
      {
        "field": "A.E",
        "lineNumber": 3
      }]
  },
  "fields": {
    "created": [
      "2017-01-19T20:11:07.977Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    2324343
  ]
}
```

Here is the mapping -

```
{
  "index1": {
    "mappings": {
      "mapping": {
        "properties": {
          "branch": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "created": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "fields": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "field": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "lineNumber": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Similarly, there are multiple documents under that index, same format, but different field data.

Now, I am trying to perform the below mentioned Elastic Search on a specific field (here - A.B), it is giving me all the results from all the documents as if it's a search for all the fields.

**I want to see only that specific field result, not all the results.**

This is my ES query -

```
POST index1/_search
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       {
         "bool": {
           "should": [
             {
               "nested": {
                 "path": "fields",
                 "query": {
                   "match_phrase": {
                     "fields.field": "A.B"
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           ]
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 }
}
```

Where am I doing wrong in the ES query?

Comment: What is the datatype of `fields.field`? Or I would be more understandable if you can add the mapping of `index1` to your question.

Comment: fields.field is of type String. I've added the mapping of index1 in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your field is not type **keyword**, then you must add the type .keyword

this is generated automatically by ES on "type": "text" fields

````
GET index1/_search
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       {
         "bool": {
           "should": [
             {
               "nested": {
                 "path": "fields",
                 "query": {
                   "match_phrase": {
                     "fields.field.keyword: "A.B"
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           ]
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 }
}```
````

Comment: You could publish in your question the mapping of the doc

Answer (score 0):

The query you have used will give you desired result. This can be better written as below if you don't require scoring:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "fields",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "fields.field": "A.B"
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {
               "size": 10
            }           
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": {
     "excludes": [
        "fields"
     ]
  }
}
```

[Inner hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-request-inner-hits.html) is what you are looking for. When there is a match elastic returns the complete nested object. If you want only the matching nested objects then you have to use `inner_hits`.

**UPDATE**: If no fields are required other than the inner hits then you can set `"_source":false`. You can also use `include` and `exclude` to [filter source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-request-source-filtering.html) as per your requirement

Comment: After adding inner_hits, I still see all the results. However, I see a small section of inner_hits at the end that has the exact 1 result which I want. 
Now, how can I get rid of all the results that are showing up in the beginning, while just keeping the last result?

Comment: Updated my answer for this.

Comment: Adding what you suggested worked, but not 100%. 
There are multiple occurrences(in my case - 8) of field "C.D" but different lineNumber in the document, which makes each entry - unique. 
However, inner_hits is showing only a few occurrences (in my case - only last 3 occurrences) and not all of them. I want to see all the occurrences of field "C.D" in my output.

Comment: Moreover, when "_source" was not set to false, the result would give me "branch" and "created" properties (see doc mapping in the question) along with the result.
However, after setting "_source": false, all that info is not available anymore.
Along with the inner_hits, except "_source", I want to see those all the properties as well. 
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Inner hits by default return top 3 documents. This can be controlled by the `size` param of `inner_hits`. I have added the link to the inner_hits documentation in my answer. Refer that for more on this.

Comment: You can use source filtering to include/exclude fields from the source as per your requirement. I this case you can use `exclude` param to exclude only `fileds` property. Then you can refer 'fields` from inner_hits result and rest of the properties from _source.

Comment: Updated my answer